# NYC: Are any Skeptics users attending the NECSS Conference this year? (2014)

Tags: discussion, conference

Who's going to http://necss.org in NYC this year?

Is anyone in contact with the organizers?

Comment: StackExchange will support the community if you want swag to distribute for example...

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I will not be able to go.  I had submitted to speak, but was not selected.  And then I got a paid speaking engagement someplace else that is on the 12th, so I ended up with a conflict.  I have emailed and corresponded with the folks there, and they are approachable and wonderful people.

I do recommend the conference. It's more intimate than something like TAM, and the workshops were fantastic last year.  If you are interested in trying to secure a sponsorship, check out this thread: [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282/200572)